# "... is not a function" error

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I'm trying to make a very basic thing in CoffeeScript:

```
...
nextId = $('.optionsTemplate').prev().children().length + 1
# 'alert nextId' gives 4, which is correct
...
newOption = /*selector of new option*/
newOption.attr 'id', 'item_options_' + nextId
newOption.attr 'name', 'item[options]['+ nextId +']'
```

So when I call "nextId" (when setting id and name) - JS console says "nextId is not a function"

I tried a couple of things:

```
# get text instead of integer
nextId.text()

# make a function
getNextId = () ->
  $('.optionsTemplate').prev().children().length + 1
```

Getting same error.

---

Here's compiled output:

```
$('.addOption').on('click', function() {
  var contents, newOption, nextId;
  nextId = $('.optionsTemplate').prev().children().length + 1;
  contents = "<div class='row'>" + $('.optionsTemplate').html() + '</div>';
  $(this).before(contents);
  newOption = $('.optionsTemplate').prev().children().eq(-1).find('.text_field');
  newOption.attr('id', 'item_options_' + nextId);
  return newOption.attr('name', 'item[options][' + nextId(+']'));
});
```

Seems Ok to me.

Comment: Please add the compiled output

Comment: just tried without return statement - didn't help

Comment: second to last line in compiled output: `nextId(` syntax error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
return newOption.attr('name', 'item[options][' + nextId(+']'));
```

Change above to

```
return newOption.attr('name', 'item[options][' + nextId +']');
```

Answer (score 0):

As has been mentioned, the problem exists in the final line:

```
newOption.attr 'name', 'item[options]['+ nextId +']'
```

The problem is that CoffeeScript is treating nextId as a function. The reason for this is that there is no space between the + symbol and the ']' string.

Adding the space as follows:

```
newOption.attr 'name', 'item[options]['+ nextId + ']'
```

makes everything work as expected. Just one of those things to be wary of with CoffeeScript - things don't always work as you expect first time due to significant whitespace.